# Pandas merge dividing a value each time it's merged

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes from the following

`df` :

```
     Name
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    C
5    D
6    D
7    D
8    D
```

and `df_value` :

```
     Name   Value
1    A      50
2    B      100
3    C      200
4    D      800
```

I want to merge both dataframes (into `df`), but with the new `Value` being worth the df_value `Value` divided by the number of occurences of `Name` in `df`

Output :

```
     Name   Value
1    A      50
2    B      100
3    C      100
4    C      100
5    D      200
6    D      200
7    D      200
8    D      200
```

A appears once, has a Value of 50 in `df_value`, so its value is 50. Same logic for B.
C appears 2 times, has a value of 200 in `df_value`, so its value is 200 / 2 = 100
D appears 4 times, has a value of 800 in `df_value`, so its value is 800 / 4 = 200

I'm pretty sure there's a really easy way to do that but I can't find it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Name` column and Series from `df_value` and divide mapped values of [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['Value'] = (df['Name'].map(df_value.set_index('Name')['Value'])
               .div(df['Name'].map(df['Name'].value_counts())))
print (df)
  Name  Value
1    A   50.0
2    B  100.0
3    C  100.0
4    C  100.0
5    D  200.0
6    D  200.0
7    D  200.0
8    D  200.0
```

Another solution, thank you @sammywemmy is mapping by already divided values:

```
df1.assign(Value=df1.Name.map(df2.set_index("Name").Value.div(df1.Name.value_counts())))
```

Solution with `merge` is possible, also added anothe alternative for counts by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Value'] = (df.merge(df_value, on='Name', how='left')['Value']
                 .div(df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size')))
```

Comment: An alternative to your solution : ``df1.assign(Value=df1.Name.map(df2.set_index("Name").Value.div(df1.Name.value_counts())))``

Comment: @sammywemmy - I am confused, for merge with left join is reset index? Because I use `df.merge(df_value, on='Name', how='left')` and index id not `Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')` but `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')`. Do you think it is bug?

Comment: it works fine when I tried it. It gives me ``Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')``

Comment: I used 1st solution which works perfectly fine, I believe others do. Thanks a lot for your help. By the way sorry for starting my index at 1, it was not a smart move from me -_-

Answer (score 1):

If it is important to keep existing dataframes as is and there is no restriction of using 2 lines of code:

```py
df1 = df.merge(df_value, on='Name', how='left')
df1['Value'] = df1.groupby('Name')[['Value']].transform(lambda x: x/len(x))
```

Otherwise one liner solution that modifies existing 'df' a bit.

```py
df['Value'] = df.merge(df_value, on='Name', how='left').groupby('Name')[['Value']].transform(lambda x: x/len(x))
```

Both give same output with different variable names:

```sh
  Name  Value
0    A   50.0
1    B  100.0
2    C  100.0
3    C  100.0
4    D  200.0
5    D  200.0
6    D  200.0
7    D  200.0
```